# Dúvida de como encolher/collapse um menu ao clicar no outro

Tags: javascript, css, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Estou com um dúvida no seguinte item, criei um SideBar com menu em bootstrap, mas eu queria que ao clicar em um, aquele que tivesse aberto encolhesse.
Exemplo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código feito até o momento:
[codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/UaU2t5Bu1U)

```css
/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #0e3c58;
}rg
p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
div.sidebar-header{
 background: #0e3c58 !important; 
}

ul.list-unstyled.CTAs{
 background: #0e3c58 !important; 
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #0e3c58 ;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6d7fcc;
 text-align: center; 
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #f39223;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #f39223;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #cc6823;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
 margin: 0px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Collapsible sidebar using Bootstrap 4</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <img src=""></img>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
            <li class="active">
                <label for="sel1">Selecione a Região:</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="regiao">
                    <option>A</option>
                    <option>B</option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Área Pública</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#Importacao" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">A</a>
                            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="Importacao">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Tipo 1</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">B</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">C</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Cargas Perigosas</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fas fa-user-lock"></i> Área Privada</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">A</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">B</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">C</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">D</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

      <!-- Page Content  -->
        <div id="content">
            <iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com/" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cara é facil você cria uma `variavel` vazia na leitura do documento.

Veja neste ex eu usei uma tabela para exemplificar seu menu:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
  last_clicked = "";
    
  $("tr").click(function(){
    
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
 
    if(last_clicked == ""){
      $(this).children('td').hide();
      last_clicked = $(this).attr('id');
    }
    else{
      
      $("#"+last_clicked).children('td').show();
      last_clicked = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).children('td').hide();
      
    }
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>Farei o exemplo com tabela</h1>
  <br><br><br>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="customers">
  <tr id="tr1">
    <th>tr1</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2">
    <th>tr2</th>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr3">
     <th>tr3</th>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr4">
    <th>tr4</th>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr5">
    <th>tr5</th>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr6">
  <th>tr6</th>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr7">
  <th>tr7</th>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>

</body>
</html>

</div>
```

coloque um id para cada ul ou div ou tr no exemplo que eu mostrei `<tr id="tr3">`

ai vc coloca um evento no click dessa tag. e ai vc esconde o id que clicou e mostra o ultimo escondido, que sera o que esta no valor da variavel:

```
$("tr").click(function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    if(last_clicked == ""){
      $(this).children('td').hide();
      last_clicked = $(this).attr('id');
    }
    else{

      $("#"+last_clicked).children('td').show();
      last_clicked = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).children('td').hide();

    }

  });
```

agora quando você clickar em outro voce esconde o aberto e abre o que clicou

Eu fiz em jquery mas voce pode usar qualquer codigo, inclusive javascript, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Fiz de outra forma, utilizando data toggle, Mas testei desta forma com JavaScript e deu certo. Muito Obrigado Julio.